# SQLAlchemy Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, ssms, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a sql file with some preliminary DB setup that I'd like to execute against a DB. The file contains SLQ that needs to be executed in separate batches (separated by the GO statement):

```
CREATE SCHEMA foo
GO
CREATE SEQUENCE [foo].[generateId]
 AS [INT]
 START WITH 61148
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -2147483648
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE
```

I currently try to do this:

```
with open("setup.sql") as f:
    with self.session() as sess:
        sess.execute(f.read())
```

However, I get an error saying `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'`. If I were to remove the creation of the schema (and thereofre the GO) from the file and then execute the following, then all works:

```
with open(sql_file) as f:
    with self.session() as sess:
        sess.execute("CREATE SCHEMA foo")
        sess.execute(f.read())
```

I've also tried with adding carriage return to the original SQL via:

```
with open(sql_file) as f:
    sql = f.read()
sql = sql.replace('\n', '\r\n')
with self.session() as sess:
    sess.execute(sql)
```

Still getting the `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'` error.

EDIT: I've also tried removing `GO` and using semicolon. The SQL in `setup.sql` then looks like:

```
CREATE SCHEMA foo;
CREATE SEQUENCE [foo].[generateTsId]
 AS [INT]
 START WITH 61148
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE -2147483648
 MAXVALUE 2147483647
 CACHE
;
```

Then I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'`. I also replace '\n' with '\r\n' because of linux -> windows.

Comment: GO is not a SQL statement - it's only used by SSMS to separate batches. You need to [terminate the statements](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons) with `;`

Comment: I tried this. I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'`. See update

Comment: `CREATE SCHEMA` must be the only statement in the batch.